# what is the number of connected components of given set?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Consider the function $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is given below:
>   \begin{cases}|t/2|, & t <-2,\\ |t+3/2| + 1/2, & -2\le t<-1,\\|t^3|, & -1\le t< 1,\\|t-3/2|^2+3/4 ,& 1\le t <2\\|t/2|,& t\ge 2 \end{cases}
>   What is the number of connected components of set $\{t\in \Bbb{R}: f \text{ is differentiable at } t\}$?

I think there  will be five connected components of the set $\{t\in \Bbb{R}: f \text{ is differentiable at } t\}$ as there are five disjoint nonempty sets.

Comment: What makes you think these $5$ sets will give $5$ different connected components? Is $f$ even differentiable on these sets?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier im not getting ur points

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.  [Scanned pages from books are forbidden on SE.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Consider [Detexify](//detexify.kirelabs.org) and [Online LaTeX editor](//www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) as a LaTeX reference.

Comment: @GNUSupporter thanks for edit my question

Comment: @GNUSupporter can u help  me this  question ?? any solution or any hints

Comment: People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts, such as calculations of the left and right derivatives at joints of intervals, and at points $t$ so that $|\text{value inside absolute sign}| = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Infact if we check $f$ is differentiable on each of the intervals (*inclusive of the critical points). Hence the number of connected components is 6.

$\rule{17cm}{1pt}$

The check:

Using definition of limit for calculating derivative viz existence of $\displaystyle \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and its value gives $f'(x)$.

By using the definition of limit  we get the following:

For $t<-2$ , $f(t)=-t/2\quad$  $\displaystyle \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\displaystyle \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{-(t+h)}{2}-\frac{-t}{2}}{h}=\frac{-1}{2}$

We rewrite $$\displaystyle f(t)=\begin {align}  \begin{cases}-(t+1), &-2\leq t\leq -3/2 \\ (t+2), &-3/2\leq t<-1\\-t^3, &-1\leq t\leq 0 \\ t^3,& 0\leq t<1\\(t-3/2)^2+3/4, & 1\leq t<2\\t/2,& t\geq 2\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Calculating derivative using limit as above we get

$$f'(t)=\begin{cases}-1, &-2<t< -3/2 \\ 1,& -3/2<t<-1\\-3t^2,& -1< t\leq 0 \\ 3t^2, &0\leq t<1\\2t-3, &1\leq t<2 \\1/2, & t\geq 2\end{cases}$$

We see that the derivative of $f$ does not exist at the points $x=-2,-3/2,-1,1,2$. Thus the intervals where derivatives exist are $(-\infty,-2),(-2,-3/2),(-3/2,-1),(-1,1),(1,2),(2,\infty).$ Hence the number of connected components are 6.

*Sorry I wanted to write exclusive of critical points.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning, esp. since any details of the check you describe are omitted.  Saying "inclusive of the critical points" is ambiguous.  A critical point is either a point where the derivative is zero or does not exist.  Points where the derivative does not exist should be *excluded* from the set defined in the problem (and missing endpoints will *disconnect* the intervals).

Comment: Nice one @YadatiKiran I also did it the same way. +1